# Why is Git committing the old version of a file?

Tags: git

I have a serious problem: Roughly two times daily, git is improperly committing an *older* version of a file that has more current modifications at the time of commit.

Workflow of the bug:

- `Example.php` is modified continuously for three hours.
- At 17:42, the file is committed and goes into SHA `200a5a3`.
- At 18:22, on reviewing the pull request, I realize that the file committed was a previous (never committed) version, coded [according to PHPStorm] at 15:34, one hour 8 minutes **before** the file was committed.
- The working copy's file is correct, and its last modification timestamp is `2014-12-30 17:04`, a full 38 minutes prior to the commit.

How is it even possible for git to 'remember' what the file was like at 3:30 when i didn't commit the changes until 5:42, anyway? Shouldn't it only know about the 5:04 version?

But more importantly, why is it happening and how can I stop it?

Comment: What are the `git` commands that you have issued ? Do you have some `git` hooks ? `crontab` entries?

Comment: I have always used the CLI but for this project, I am using the GUI SourceTree, for the first time.

Comment: Did you `git add` the file at 15:34, and then run `git commit` at 17:42?

Comment: @WilliamPursell No, the file already existed previously to all this.

Comment: Ignore the gui, go to the working dir and run `git diff --cached`

Comment: `git add` doesn't just add the new file.  It is an alias for `git stage`, and it's purpose is to add new changes to the index.  If you make a change after `git add`, those changes may not be in the index, and will be ignored by the next commit.

Comment: @WilliamPursell *`git add` doesn't just add the new file. It is an alias for `git stage` [...]* That's a tad misleading; `add` and `stage` are completely equivalent Git verbs, but, strictly speaking, `git add` is not a Git alias for `git stage`.

Comment: Strictly speaking, `git stage` is an alias for `git add`.  Not an alias in the sense that it needs to be added to a .gitconfig, but an alias in the sense that `git add` existed first, and code was later added so that git recognizes `stage` and treats as if it were the verb `add`.

Comment: @WilliamPursell We're on the same page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHPStorm (and all of the Intellij family of IDEs) likes to do funky things with source control in order to normalize the source control interface for the user (So that version control looks the same whether you use Git, Mercurial or Subversion).

For that reason, I never use my IDE to do my commits (That, and because PHPStorm doesn't support PGP signed commits with `git commit -S`).

What is most likely happening is that PHPStorm is calling `git add <file>` at some point, and for some unknown reason fails to call it again before committing. So old changes are added to the index (and then committed) while there are still changes pending on the file in the working directory.

For that reason, I suggest that you do not rely on PHPStorm to handle source control, and always use the CLI.

Comment: confirmed as the problem.